# Calculate watts after stepdown

Tags: conversion

If I start with 120 volts and 2 watts then step-down to 5 v. How many watts do I have now?
Where can I find an online calculator for this?

Comment: Conservation of energy (or power which is energy per second) is one of the fundamental principles of the universe.

Comment: **Conservation of Energy** requires that the total of all energy input equals the total of all energy output, but I assume you're only interested in how much *electrical* energy is *delivered to the load* (not including heat, acoustics, EMI, or other forms of energy). How many watts are available to the load, depends on the step-down converter's efficiency (not given) -- so available load current cannot be determined from the question as presented. The usual approach would be to measure how much current the load draws at 5VDC, then evaluate the converter's efficiency at that operating point.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is clearly a case where the OP needs to be taught what he doesn't know instead of being beaten for not knowing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with 2 watts, you'll have 2 watts available for the load, minus the losses in whatever's stepping the 120 volts down to 5 volts.

For example, if a transformer with a 5 volt secondary is doing the conversion and is  loaded with a device that is dissipating 2 watts, then the transformer must supply whatever secondary current is required by the device which, in this case, would be:

$$ I = \frac{P}{E} = \frac {2W}{5V} = 0.4 \text{ amperes.}$$

The power, however, must come from the 120 volt source and, if the transformer were perfect, the transformer primary would need to draw:

$$ I = \frac{P}{E} = \frac {2W}{120V} \approx 0.0167 \text{ amperes}$$

from the 120 volt source, in order for energy to be conserved.

In that vein then, if the load dissipated less (or more) than 2 watts, a perfect  transformer would take only the amount of power from the source required to satisfy the load.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is conserved. The power remains the same, minus inefficiencies of the converter. If your converter is 75% efficient, you will have 1.5W available at its output.

Answer (score 0):

Transformers only transforms voltages and currents while maintaining the ratios between them thus the power at both of its sides remain same, ideally...